# Best method to maintain user answer in MCQ exam

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, web-applications

In my MCQ exam project, I`m maintaining the user answer in session variable,
when the exam ends I push the answers in database.

So my question is,

- Should I maintain the answers in session variable?
- When should the answers to be pushed into database
- If I`m maintaining the answer in session(memory), how to straggle with power-failure(lost of session variable), should I use xml file for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question.

The answer is no, since on power failure the user will end up loosing all his work and won't be very happy.

I think the best thing to do is  for you to store the answers on a temp table with a unique identifier (I imagine users have to authenticate before the start the exam). Once they are done, you move the records from the temp table to the actual table.

In conclusion, Session is not a good place. Either a temp storage on your side (temp table) or perhaps a cookie, but you could run into more issues with that...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have one question that if I`m storing answer in temp table, then each time users answers the questions it makes a database trip, if number of users are large then will it form any performance degrade?

Comment: As long as you are not using MS Access for your database, I believe you will be fine. Database connections are pooled and a database `trip` takes milliseconds to complete. It's just a straight insert into a table. Believe me, even a page with 4 gazillion visitors per day would do something like this.